# Fit ColumnHeaders to ListView's width, this code needs an explanation and wonder if there is a standard way?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I found this code (a loop) which can fit the total width of all ColumnHeaders to the width of a listview (of course if the ListView's width is large enough, otherwise there will be a horizontal scrollbar displayed).

```
foreach(ColumnHeader ch in myListView.Columns){
     ch.Width = -2;
}
```

I've just tried changing the value -2 to some other values and it didn't work. I need an explanation on this code, why does it have to be -2 and not any other?

By the way, if possible do you know any other (standard?) way to do this (fit the total width of all ColumnHeaders to the width of a ListView)?

Your help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: I tested and see that we only need to set the width of the last Column of ListView to -2, all the others can be set to arbitrary values, of course as I said, if the total width is large enough (or the ListView's width is small enough) there will be a horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: It seems that there are only 3 kinds of values, 0 (the width = 0 as it means), -2 (the width fits), and all the remaining negative values (the width doesn't fit, there is a gap between the right edge of the last column and the right border of the ListView).

Comment: This may be some kind of indicative value which is predefined, it's similar to constant of style and I wonder why isn't there some style Property for this instead.

Comment: You would have to post more code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no automatic way to do this beyond what you have found. This is documented at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761163(v=vs.85).aspx though you can't see the value for LVSCW_AUTOSIZE_USEHEADER, it is -2.

In order to do this yourself, you need to react to the ListView being resized, and calculate the widths yourself. There is an event for the resizing. Then you use listview.ClientSize.Width - SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth for the total width to account for the scrollbar.

Comment: Thank you, this is some kind of 'hack' to send message to the listview via assigning Width right in .NET. Could you post the link to some page documenting the values of LVSCW_AUTOSIZE and LVSCW_AUTOSIZE_USEHEADER for me? I can't understand why Microsoft doesn't show their values right in the page from your link, they require me to search for those constants? And I've searched for minutes (above 15) without find anything, why is it so difficult to find them while any WIN32 api function can be searched easily (right at the first link in result page)...

Comment: All such constants should be documented and easy to find, they are related to Win32 API functions and of course very important to know, except you work in C++ environment where you can use their names, you have to know exactly their values. I wonder is this a signal of fading Win32 away gradually? I remember I could search for these constants (or anything related to Win32) easily 5-7 years ago, now they seem to be obsolete?

Comment: Win32 is not going anywhere. I don't know why you're having trouble finding them, they come up easily for me in a Google search.